# Trying to print Enums to resemble a deck of cards but can't print object just description

Tags: java, object, printing, enums

I'm trying to make a deck of cards using enums for the suit and card values. I'm trying to print off the lists of enums but I only get their numerical value and not the objects name.  I have watched the video on newboston over 9 thousand times and can't seem to get this figured out.

This is my printout when I run the program

> 123456789101112131 2 3 4

My overall goal is to put these enums into an arraylist where I can deal them out the players. When I print these statements shouldn't it tell me (Ace, King, Queen....ect)?

PRINT STATEMENTS

```
for(CardValue card : CardValue.values()) {//Enhanced for loop
            System.out.printf("%s",card);//I tried using different styles of print to see if it would change anything
                }
        for(Suit card : Suit.values()) {//Enhanced for loop
            System.out.println(card.toString());
                }
```

ENUM CLASS CardValue

```
    public enum CardValue
    {
      ACE(1),
      TWO(2),
      THREE(3),
      FOUR(4),
      FIVE(5),
      SIX(6),
      SEVEN(7),
      EIGHT(8),
      NINE(9),
      TEN(10),
      JACK(11),
      QUEEN(12),
      KING(13);

      private final int cardValue;

      private CardValue (int value)
      {
        this.cardValue = value;
      }

      public int getCardValue() {
        return cardValue;
      }

      public String toString(){
        return String.format("%s", cardValue);

      }
    }
```

Enum Class Suit

```
public enum Suit
{
  HEARTS(1),
  SPADES(2),
  CLUBS(3),
  DIAMONDS(4);

  private final int suit;

  private Suit (int value)
  {
    this.suit = value;
  }

  public int getCardSuit() {
    return suit;
  }
  public String toString(){
      return String.format("%s", suit);
  }
}
```

Comment: you should tag with a language or some other identifier other than those generic ones you used.  is that java?

Comment: Yeah, Sorry about that. it slipped my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `toString` methods should look like this:

```
 public String toString(){
    return String.format("%s", this.name());
  }
```

You can also just leverage the built in name() method directly when printing the enumeration values. In your code example you were simply printing the description field that you defined yourself in the two enumerations. The name() method will return the actual string value of the  enumeration 'name', the value that uniquely defines the current enumeration constant.

Comment: +1 it would be more helpful to op if you explain the reason for his output also.

Comment: Added a better description of why he was getting incorrect output.